# Using lapply to list percentage of null variables in every column in R

Tags: r, apply, lapply, mapply

I was given a large csv that is 115 columns across and 1000 rows. The columns have a variety of data, some is character-based, some is integer, etc. However, the data has a LOT of null variables of varying types (NA, -999, NULL, etc.).

What I want to do is write a script that will generate a LIST of columns where over 30% of the data in the column is a NULL of some type.

To do this, I wrote a script to give me the null percentage (as decimal) for one column. *This script works fine for me.*

```
length(which(indata$ObservationYear == "" | is.na(indata$ObservationYear) |
indata$ObservationYear == "NA" | indata$ObservationYear == "-999" |
indata$ObservationYear == "0"))/nrow(indata)
```

I want to write a script to do this for all columns. I believe I need to use the lapply function.

I attempted to do this here, however, I can't seem to get this script to work at all:

```
Null_Counter <- lapply(indata, 2, length(x),
                   length(which(indata == "" | is.na(indata) | indata == "NA" | indata == "-999" | indata == "0")))
                   names(indata(which(0.3>=Null_Counter / nrow(indata))))
```

I get the following errors:

```
Error in match.fun(FUN) : '2' is not a function, character or symbol
```

and:

```
Error: could not find function "indata"
```

Ideally, what I want it to give me is a vector LIST of all column names where the percentage of all null variables (NA, -999, 0, NULL) is over 30%.

Can anyone help?

Comment: `lapply` don't need a `MARGIN`.  It is for `apply`.  You can check the examples in `?lapply`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to use apply rather than lapply which apply a function to a list.
Try this:

```
Null_Counter <- apply(indata, 2, function(x) length(which(x == "" | is.na(x) | x == "NA" | x == "-999" | x == "0"))/length(x))
Null_Name <- colnames(indata)[Null_Counter >= 0.3]
```

Comment: Thanks so much. My final solution was:


    null_counts <- apply(indata, 2, function(x)
    length(which(x == "" | is.na(x) | x == "NA" | x == "-999" | x == "0")))
null_flags <- colnames(indata[which(0.5<=null_counts/nrow(indata))])

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different way to do this in `data.table`:

```
#first, make a reproducible example:
library(data.table)
#make it so that all columns have ~30% "NA" as you define it
dt<-as.data.table(replicate(
  115,sample(c(1:100,"",NA,"NA",-999,0),size=1000,replace=T,
             prob=c(rep(.007,100),rep(.06,5)))))
```

Now, figure out which are troublesome:

```
x<-as.matrix(dt[,lapply(.SD,function(x){
  mean(is.na(x) | x %in% c("","NA","-999","0"))})])
colnames(x)[x>.3]
```

There's probably a more concise way of doing this, but it's eluding me.

If you're trying to drop those columns, this could be adjusted:

```
dt[,!colnames(x)[x>.3],with=F]
```